# Play Store promo video does not autoplay

Tags: android, youtube, google-play, google-play-console

I have released my first app developed for android. I have set up everything in the google play console and also used a promotional video for my store listing.

For some reason this video is not autoplaying if you check the app in Google Play Store. The videos of other apps do start muted and in autoplay.

Do you have any idea what may be the problem there?

**That is my game**: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.SlevinKGames.SansasWorld

**This is the video I am using**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCVJj1o7cao

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `The videos of other apps do start muted and in autoplay` = If you need your video to autoplay "muted", add the `autoplay=1&mute=1` to your video URL.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but actually the video URL required from Play-Store is no embed url, where those parameter work, but instead the normal video URL. The play store should on his own mute and autoplay this video afaik.

Comment: @SlevinKGames - I have the same problem and from the link I can see you somehow made it work. How did you managed it? What was the problem?

Comment: As @TomAtom, I see you made it work. I have the same problem and would be grateful if you could help solve the mystery.

Comment: @niko.mikulicic in the end I did nothing... I was checking it day by day about week and it didn't work. I gave up. Then I checked it after about 14 days and it worked!
 So, it looks to me like there is some processing on GP side which may take a pretty long time. (Mine is here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sbcgames.marblesgarden)

Comment: @TomAtom, thanks for response. Interesting. Maybe it is just a matter of processing time. Mine also began to work a day later. However, I did fix the following in the meantime (from: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9866151?hl=en#zippy=%2Cpreview-video): 
`Use: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yourvideoid , Don't use: https://youtu.be/yourvideoid`
Anyway, it works now (here's the link as well: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hr.mipmap.rollplayer)